# Load Photo Images to iOS App Slider with Placeholder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

how can i solve my problem, loading xxx.png or jpg Photos from web with placeholder.
that is to run in the photoslider.

my attempted code:

// Photo Slider

```
NSString *sliderimage01 = [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage1"]];
NSString *sliderimage02 = [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage2"]];
NSString *sliderimage03 = [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage3"]];
NSString *sliderimage04 = [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage4"]];
NSString *sliderimage05 = [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage5"]];

self.imagesData = @[sliderimage01, sliderimage02, sliderimage03, sliderimage04, sliderimage05];
for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
index=0;
```

thanks

Comment: ...and what is your problem?

Comment: how do I have to use NSString correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:
Method `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` is probably defined in `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`. If so, it does „return“ `void`, so all your `NSString *sliderimageXX` do not contain references to your images.
Moreover, you assign to your variable `imageView`, that I assume is an `UIImageView` object, 5 times the same image (loaded from `url`) with different placeholder images, but only the last one will be stored since the others are overwritten.
So if you want to add different `imageViews` to your `scrollView`, you had to assign the images, using `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`, in your `for` loop, i.e. replace there

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];
```

by something like

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage"]];
```

Of course, you probably want to assign different images and placeholders, using something like

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url[i] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeholderImages[i]]];
```

I hope I got it right!